# Binding a list of strings (sentences) to a Label control (into a paragraph) such that each sentence is a Span control in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-databinding

In my ViewModel, I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects where each object has a `string` property. I want to bind this list of objects to a `Label` control such that the string property of each object is a `Span` of the `Label` control.
Is this even possible? Need help

### Example:

#### Model

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Sentence { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Sentences { get; set; }
}
```

#### The xaml I need

This is what I am hoping to get after binding

```
<Label x:Name="LblParagraph">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.Spans>
                <Span Text="Sentence from MyObject 1"></Span>
                <Span Text="Sentence from MyObject 2"></Span>
                <Span Text="Sentence from MyObject 3"></Span>
                <Span Text="Sentence from MyObject i"></Span>
                <Span Text="Sentence from MyObject ObservableCollection.Count"></Span>
            </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

How do I write my xaml view to get the above xml as the outcome

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this purely in XAML.  You would probably need to write C# to build the layout.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately** , `Span` can not bind a list of strings for `Lable` in **Xaml** , however there is way by using code to convert it to be used for `Label` in **Xaml**.

**Xaml** code as follow :

```
<Label x:Name="LblParagraph">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <FormattedString.Spans>
                <Span Text="{Binding .}"></Span>
            </FormattedString.Spans>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Create a method used to transfer `List<string>` to `string` in  **ContentPage**

```
public string ConvertStrings(List<string> objects)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i< objects.Count; i++)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append("Sentence from MyObject " + objects[i] +"\n");
    }
    stringBuilder.Append("Sentence from MyObject Count is : " + objects.Count);

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Then used for binding :

```
List<string> strs = new List<string>();
strs.Add("1");
strs.Add("2");
strs.Add("3");
strs.Add("4");
strs.Add("5");
string labelSource = ConvertStrings(strs);
BindingContext = labelSource;
```

The effect :

[image]